# Можно ли добавить расширяемые антиспам фильтры?

Tags: предложение, вопросы, удаление-вопросов, спам

Последнее время участились случаи спама с [криком о помощи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1001321/revisions), причем в этих просьбах деньги просят перевести практически всегда на [одну и ту же карту](https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&q=%225536+9137+5246+8484%22).

Можно ли сделать голосование с обратной связью? Например пользователи голосующие за закрытие вопроса как спам могли бы вводить несколько ключевых слов, которые категоризировали бы вопросы как спам автоматически. Разумеется должна набраться критическая масса таких заявок - например если `N` разных человек указали номер карты как спам, то все последующие вопросы, в которых встречается номер этой карты будут закрываться автоматически.

Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Думаю, что стоит оповещать о последовательности цифр, составляющей банковскую карту, и о популярных web-кошельках. Может, даже задерживать такие вопросы перед публикацией. Ваше предложение хорошее, но нужно действовать оперативно, пока [кто-то](http://lurkmore.to/Лох) не пострадал от этого.

Comment: Не наберётся у нас 10 голосующих.

Comment: @Suvitruf, но `N` то точно наберется ? :-D

Comment: @MaxU вообще, лучше, чтоб система при отправке вопроса/ответа проверяла его содержимое регуляркой и автоматом ставила тревогу модераторам.

Comment: @Suvitruf, идея хорошая, но как сделать эти регулярки с обратной связью? Модераторы не справятся с роботами, IMO...

Comment: @MaxU на модераторов не такая уж большая нагрузка. Там всего пара десятков тревог в день.

Comment: Любой пост с любым номером карты по-любому подозрительный, регулярка простая будет к тому же

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а как регулярка должна узнать, что это именно номер карты, а не нечто совершенно другое, что по какой-то причине оказалось в коде вопроса? Или это не случайный пример номера карты, который как-то нужен для поиска ошибки в коде?

Comment: Smoke detector уже есть, его можно тренировать через чат. Но я не уверен, все это могут делать или нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я не говорю, что надо как-то сразу безусловно удалять топик или блокировать публикацию. Просто к нему нужно особое внимание, например, автоматическая тревога для модератора